# How can you use the FILEOPEN in BBj to create a Filedialog?

Tags: bbj

[In the Documentation](https://documentation.basis.cloud/BASISHelp/WebHelp/mnemonic/syswindow/fileopen_mnemonic_create_file_open_dialog_bbj.htm?Highlight=fileopen) it is stated like this:
`'FILEOPEN'(prompt,path,name,ext[,filters[,mode]])`

But what parameters do you need to use to be able to display the dialog?
Any samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are documented in [this page](https://documentation.basis.cloud/BASISHelp/WebHelp/commands/fileopen_function_create_file_open_dialog.htm?Highlight=fileopen)

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| prompt | Text to display in the title bar of the dialog. |
| path | Default directory for the file to be opened in the dialog. |
| name | Default name for the file to be opened in the dialog. Use the empty string ("") to avoid setting a default filename. |
| ext | Default extension (usually 3 characters, do not include the dot) for the file to be opened in the dialog. Use the empty string ("") to avoid setting a default extension. |
| filters | One or more filters in the following format: "text description" + $0a$ + "mask" [+$0a$ + "text description" + $0a$ + "mask" ...] The mask specifies an extension, in the format "*.ext" or "*.*"; two or more masks are separated with semicolons. The filter, if included, indicates which files will appear in the list. For example: REM Illustrate the use of the FILEOPEN() function REM Build filters for brc/arc and all files FILTER$="Binary Resource Files"+$0a$+"*.brc;*.brf" FILTER$=FILTER$+$0a$+"ASCII Resource Files"+$0a$+"*.arc" FILTER$=FILTER$+$0a$+"All Files (*.*)"+$0a$+"*.*" REM Starting directory is the default Directory FILE_DIR$="" REM Use FILEOPEN() to get name of file to open FILE_NAME$=FILEOPEN("Open Resource File",FILE_DIR$,"","",FILTER$) REM display file name returned PRINT FILE_NAME$ |

```
rem ' clientfile.txt
precision 6
tc! = bbjapi().getThinClient()
fs! = tc!.getClientFileSystem()
filter$ = ""
filter$ = filter$ + "Text Files (*.txt)"+$0a$+"*.txt"+$0a$
filter$ = filter$ + "HTML Files (*.htm;*.html)"+$0a$+"*.htm;*.html"+$0a$
filter$ = filter$ + "Image Files (*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)"+$0a$+"*.png;*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif"+$0a$
filter$ = filter$ + "All Files (*.*)"+$0a$+"*.*"+$0a$
i = msgbox("Test client fileopen + copy file from client to server")
clientfile$ = fileopen("Pick a client file","","","",filter$,mode="client")
i = msgbox(clientfile$,0,"Selected client file")
if pos("::"=clientfile$) then goto eoj
cf! = fs!.getClientFile(clientfile$)
i = msgbox("Copy "+clientfile$+" to the server")
t = tim
serverfile$ = cf!.copyFromClient()
t = tim - t
t = t * 3600
serverfile = unt
open (serverfile)serverfile$
serverfile$ = fid(serverfile)(9)
bytes = dec(fin(serverfile)(1,4))
close (serverfile)
i = msgbox("Copied client file "+clientfile$+" to server file "+serverfile$+" ("+str(bytes)+" bytes; "+str(t)+" seconds)",0,"Copied from client to server")
i = msgbox("Test server fileopen + copy file from server to client")
serverfile$ = fileopen("Pick a server file","","","",filter$)
i = msgbox(serverfile$,0,"Selected server file")
if pos("::"=serverfile$) then goto eoj
clientfile! = new java.io.File(serverfile$)
clientfile$ = clientfile!.getName()
clientfile$ = filesave("Save to client","",clientfile$,"",filter$,mode="client")
if pos("::"=clientfile$) then goto eoj
i = msgbox("Copy server file "+serverfile$+" to client file "+clientfile$)
cf! = fs!.getClientFile(clientfile$)
cf!.copyToClient(serverfile$)
i = msgbox("Copied server file "+serverfile$+" to client file "+clientfile$,0,"Copied from server to client")
eoj:
release
```